# Getting Started with MVCScaffolding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

I have gone through many of the MVC tutorials and now I want to create a prototype mvc app of an existing database.

I have installed the MVCScaffolding package and I want to use it with an existing database.  Has anyone found steps to go about doing this? I have looked but have been unable to figure out how to get it to work.

I want to connect to a sql server database and have the model created from it. Then scaffold out the views and controller.

Is there something I am not understanding here? Is this how MVC Scaffolding works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this might be a little complex to work with at first, but then you will discover the beauty of it. [Check this tutorial out](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/), it helped me a lot when I started Asp.Net MVC 3, also Asp.Net site helped me a lot. Scaffolding is nothing more than a bunch of templates to make your life easier, nothing more. You could also check [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/05/ef-code-first-and-data-scaffolding-with-the-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx) about this same topic.

Good luck!

Comment: I have been reading ScottGu's blog the past couple days. I have read through that tutorial you posted as well just havent completed it yet.

Comment: Hey, I am glad you are making progress. Check the following tutorials for DataFirst/CodeFirst with Entity Framework 4.1 which also helped me on my learning curve.  Datafirst: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489 CodeFirst: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685467 Good luck :) - Hanlet